# import excel spreadsheet data into MYSQL database using java

Tags: java, jdbc, import-from-excel

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;

public class assessmentdatabase_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try {

　　　     Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root",
                    "pass");
            con.setAutoCommit(false);
            PreparedStatement pstm = null;
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("filepath");
            POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);

            HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Row row;
            for (int i = 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {

                row = sheet.getRow(i);
                String Process = row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                double Level = row.getCell(2).getNumericCellValue();
                double A = row.getCell(3).getNumericCellValue();
                double B = row.getCell(4).getNumericCellValue();
                double C = row.getCell(5).getNumericCellValue();


                String sql = "INSERT INTO description_process_level VALUES('" + Process + "','" + Level + "','" + A + "',`" + B + "`,`" + C +)";
                pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.execute();
                System.out.println("Import rows " + i);
            }
            con.commit();
            pstm.close();
            con.close();
            input.close();
            System.out.println("Success import excel to mysql table");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have debug the entire code and it is compiling till line 47 and showing the error at line 48. I want to import this data to mysql.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '61.166666666666664`,`75.25`,'61.166666666666664',`61.166666666666664`,`75.25`)' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1192)
    at fibb.assessmentdatabase_3.main(assessmentdatabase_3.java:48)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Query with this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO description_process_level (process, level, a, b, c) VALUES('" + Process + "'," + Level + "," + A + "," + B + "," + C +")";
```

1. You missed " in the end,
2. You don't need to use ' for Double, just for String

I advice to use :

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO description_process_level (process, level, a, b, c) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);

pstm.setString(1, Process);
pstm.setDouble(2, Level);
pstm.setDouble(3, A);
pstm.setDouble(4, B);
pstm.setDouble(5, C);
```

Here is an exemple how to use prepared statement:

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/

Comment: i tried this but now it started showing different error that is  -  Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Comment: yes of course how many parameters there are in your database, you should to specifie your parameters that you want to insert, like that, String sql = "INSERT INTO description_process_level (p1, p2, p3, p4, p5) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; you can see my edit

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO description_process_level (process,level,a,b,c) VALUES (Process,Level,A,B,C)";                           pstm = (PreparedStatement) con.prepareStatement(sql);            pstm.setString(1, Process);
    pstm.setDouble(2, Level);
    pstm.setDouble(3, A);
    pstm.setDouble(4, B);
    pstm.setDouble(5, C);
still the same error is coming

Comment: no in values just make VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?) , thats all

Comment: i edit my answer this should work for you if you dont have any problem in your database

Comment: Import rows 1
Import rows 2
Import rows 3
Import rows 4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at fibb.assessmentdatabase_3.main(assessmentdatabase_3.java:35)
Import rows 5
Import rows 6
Import rows 7
Import rows 8
Import rows 9
Import rows 10
Import rows 11              In my excel sheet the data is available till row no 11 and this program is executing even after the 11th row and accordingly showing the null pointer error. how should i stop this program at row 11

Comment: can you please help me out.

Comment: This is another error, did my answer worked with you?

Comment: sorry but i can`t share my excel sheet is there any other way so that you can help us out.

Comment: change your PreparedStatement with a Statement like this int exc = statement.executeUpdate(query);

Comment: I have added a if(i==12) break; inside the for loop now it is saying that the data is imported but when i am checking my database the table set is empty.                                                                                                Import rows 1
Import rows 2
Import rows 3
Import rows 4
Import rows 5
Import rows 6
Import rows 7
Import rows 8
Import rows 9
Import rows 10
Import rows 11
Success import excel to mysql table